# Caching custom user properties in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, caching, authorization

I have custom UserInfo and UserAuthorization objects in my app, which determine what is displayed and what actions a user can perform on each page. At the moment this information needs to be retreived for every request to the server. Would it be possible/sensible to cache this information somehow? Can anyone suggest some good google search terms as I haven't managed to find anything. Thanks.

Comment: Retrieved from where? Do you want to cache on the server-side (to avoid extra trips to database) or on client-side (to avoid extra trips to server)?

Comment: Server side I think. I want to reduce the number of remote service calls my web server has to make on each action. I'm currently querying 4 to 5 different databases inorder to perform any action.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be sensible to cache
>   this information somehow?

No. You could probably use session state if you really wanted but have you determined that loading this user information per request is really an issue?

Comment: No I haven't noticed performance issues as yet, but I'm only running on my local machine at the moment. I'd like to reduce the number of remote server calls partly because it just feels messy to have to pull data from so many places all the time. I thought user caching was fairly common. If you think it's a bad idea though, that's a good enough answer for me.

Comment: Why would you be pulling so much data? It sounds like on each web request you're accessing 4 or 5 databases to validate the user. Why?